# External hard drive not accessible on Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: hard-drive

I am having trouble to access my external hard drive since last week (all my important data are on it).
My computer knows that it is there. When I ask `lsusb`, I get:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1058:1234 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Western Digital is the one I want to open.

Now if I ask for more info using `dmesg | tail -n 50`, I get normal stuff until

```
[337725.521362] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Spinning up disk...
[337725.521724] ses 4:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[337725.521731] ses 4:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[337726.542170] .
```

I am wondering what that means and if anyone have some idea to save my disk (and 3 years of work).

Comment: Firstly I'd stop trying to use it, and assess the drive's health (this is done from the electronics of the drive, so won't do any harm allowing whatever left is remaining on the drive to be used for data recovery).  Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools to read the drive's inbuilt SMART health stats.

Comment: Where was your external hard drive  last successfully used? Windows with Fast Boot?

Comment: It was on my previous computer with ubuntu.